# How to use viewModels in Kmm shared module for both IOS and Android Screens

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, viewmodel, kmm

I am new in Kmm I have create a UI with Jetpack compose for android and swift ui for IOS in simple application in kmm, so in shared module I just want to create **viewModels** for both android and iOS activities but I don't find any proper solution for this.

Comment: In KMM the viewmodel would not be common for both the app as this is the part of the presentation layer but you can create common use case, domin and data layer

Answer (score 1):

Had tried with this library to  https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-mvvm
to achieve Clean MVVM in KMM project

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33152499)

Comment: Understood your point, link can become invalid.